# Xcode markup for autocompletion

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, documentation

I could not find anything in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/MarkupFunctionality.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH54-SW1) on how to add documentation that will show in the autocompletion. For instance, if I do:

```
/**
wether the rendering computation should be skipped
*/
public var isPaused = false
```

This will work fine with the `option + click` documentation querying:

[image]

But not in the autocompletion:

[image]

How can I get something like:

[image]

Where a short description shows at the bottom?